# Why don't you need to wrap a curly brackets outside of the colon in dart/flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

```
enum BinType {
  Wheelie(
    description: 'wheelie bin',
  ),

}
```

Hi there, I am trying to learn dart and flutter. I am trying to understand the code above. I know how to code in Javascript. I want to know why you don't need to wrap a curly bracket outside of the colon. Is this an object?

```
 description: 'wheelie bin'
```

How do you decide when to use the keyword enum ?

Comment: Read the [Dart Language Tour](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour) first. `description` is a *named parameter*.

Answer (score 0):

On dart, you will get **Enhanced Enums** And it will be

```dart
enum BinType {
  Wheelie(
    description: 'wheelie bin',
  );

  final String description;
  const BinType({required this.description});
}
```

It is using named constructor. More about [enumerated-types](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#enumerated-types)

Comment: thanks, what is the purpose of the label - Wheelie ?

Comment: `Wheelie` is a enum type, and it will be use on your code like `BinType.Wheelie` in general. you can attached links and [this will help](https://pub.dev/packages/enhanced_enum)